# Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined error. How to type text in codeMirror element using Selenium WebDriver and Java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codemirror

I am trying to enter text in textarea. As I know this field is CodeMirror. This is my code:

```
{...

WebElement scriptField = 

this.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(".CodeMirror-line>span"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.getDriver();

String query = "text";

js.executeScript("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(\""+ query +"\");", scriptField);

}
```

And I have this error at last line of my code:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException  : unknown error: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined`

I am not sure to which webelement I should refer to in scriptField variable. When I am typing text (manually) it appears in this element: `".CodeMirror-line>span"`. So Am I correct?

There is fragment of my DOM on attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Whatever the `scriptField` is, it doesn not have a property `CodeMirror`. Why? You'll need to check that for yourself, there's not enough information. Probably (and most likely) because DOM elements don't have those kinds of properties.

Comment: I would try to remove `.CodeMirror` from `js.executeScript` line. You are already providing this element as an argument to `executeScript` method

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the WebElement, scriptField in this case, simply use sendKeys() method.

```
WebElement scriptField = this.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(".CodeMirror-line>span"));
scriptField.sendKeys("your text");
```

You can also clear the field before adding your text in it.

```
WebElement scriptField = this.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(".CodeMirror-line>span"));
scriptField.clear();
scriptField.sendKeys("your text");
```

Comment: This will probably throw an error saying it can't focus on the element.

Comment: My answer assumed he has the element captured already. As he explained in his question he was trying to update the text using JavaScriptExecutor.

Comment: Yes, it throws error saying it can't focus on the element as @marcel written

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the actual text inside the span element, try this:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = " + query + ";", scriptField);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped in my case.

Comment: Glad to help, if my answer helped you, please accept it as answered by clicking on the checkmark next to this answer

Answer (score 0):

To change the existing text to **`myText`** use the following code block :

```
WebElement scriptField = this.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("pre.CodeMirror-line>span"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) this.getDriver();
String js = "arguments[0].innerHTML='myText';";
jse.executeScript(js, scriptField);
```